# URL::forceSchema not working before login

Tags: laravel, https

I'm using `URL::forceSchema('https')` to force SSL on my Laravel 5.3 application. However, it only works after login (even the login page isn't being covered with https).

I'm using [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) with the following configuration:

```
'headers' => [
        (defined('Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED') ? Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED : 'forwarded') => null,
        \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP    => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST  => null,
        \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
        \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT  => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
    ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got it working by adding the following code to *register* method of AppServiceProvider.

```
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
   $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
}
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/force-ssl-secure-routes-in-laravel-52?page=1

Answer (score 1):

Add a config called "force_https" in your config file, and don't forget to add it into your .env.

config/app.php

```php
     'force_https' => env('FORCE_HTTPS', false),
```

Then, in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php :

```php
     /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        if (config('app.force_https')) {
            $url->forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

This way, whenever you serve your app behind a reverse proxy where connection between proxy and app is insecure, you can set the FORCE_HTTPS to `true`, and `false` if your local dev don't require one.