# Laravel 5.7 AJAX POST request Canceled

Tags: php, https, laravel-5.7

I am using Ubuntu with `SSL` enable on my server. When I send a simple `post` request using `$.ajax()` on `https`, what happens is, request with `https` gets canceled & another request on same `URL` is sent with `http`. Which in turn gives `Mixed Content Error`

I tried allowing CORS on server side using following code in `Middleware` & registering it with all routes, but no luck.

```
return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
```

This is my route, which I am calling:
    Route::post('sample-route', 'OrderController@Sample');
This is my `ajax` code:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'https://my-domain/sample-route/',
    dataType: 'json',
    'type': 'post',
    'headers': {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(resp, status, xhr){
            console.log(resp);
    },
});
```

I also added a check in `AppServiceProvider` to force all requests on production to be sent on `https`. Following is that code:

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100382/urlforceschema-not-working-before-login maybe it helps

Comment: Just tried this, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple things I fixed it by removing trailing `/` from `URL`
I don't know the reason, but removing it solved the problem