# Laravel Application mixed content

Tags: php, laravel, docker, https, traefik

I have a docker swarm setup, with traefik running as a reverse proxy.
I want to install [this](https://github.com/theryecatcher/flox) Laravel application with docker-compose.
The application is basically a selfhosted Movie/TV Watchlist.

After i edited the docker-compose to fit my swarm setup i fired the container up. 
When i tried to reach it locally through 192.168.1.178:6030 it worked, but, when i tried to access it through my domain https://flox.mydomain.com i got an empty page, and when i looked at the console with F12 it gave me these errors:

[image: mixed-content]
Then i went ahead and changed the APP_URL from http://localhost to https://flox.mydomain.com in the .env file which gave me the same result.

Then after doing some research i tried to force https by editing  /backend/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

I added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;` at the beginning of the file and
`URL::forceScheme('https');` inside the `boot` function.

This helped resolve all the above mentioned Errors and the Application finally loaded and i thought this would be the end of it. But that's not how the cookie crumbled.

I added a few movies to my watchlist, and then later when i looked at the list, not all movies loaded but there is a "Load more" button at the end of the website, and when i click that button, the old familliar "mixed content" error came back.

[image: LoadMore]

[image: mixedcontent-error2]

I have no Idea why this is not served over https. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

-----------------------------EDIT------------------------------

My app.blade.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta id="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

  <title>Flox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('assets/app.css') }}">
  <link href="{{ url('assets/favicon.ico?v=3') }}" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">

</head>
<body
  data-env="{{ config('app.env') }}"
  data-url="{{ url('/') }}"
  data-uri="{{ config('app.CLIENT_URI') }}"
  data-poster-tmdb="{{ config('services.tmdb.poster') }}"
  data-poster-subpage-tmdb="{{ config('services.tmdb.poster_subpage') }}"
  data-backdrop-tmdb="{{ config('services.tmdb.backdrop') }}"
  data-auth="{{ Auth::check() }}"
  data-language="{{ $lang }}"
  class="{{ Auth::check() ? 'logged' : 'guest' }}"
>

  <div id="app">
    @if(Request::is('login'))
      <login></login>
    @else
      <modal></modal>
      <site-header></site-header>
      <router-view></router-view>
      <site-footer></site-footer>
    @endif
  </div>

  <script src="{{ url('assets/vendor.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('assets/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe `APP_URL` in .env file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I already set the APP_URL in .env to `https://flox.mydomain.com` this was the first thing i tried. - didnt work

Comment: Prefixed with `https://`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being vague

Comment: Then double check in blade file (layout or somewhere else where head section is loaded) how `app.js` and `app.css` [and other console logged urls] are loaded/requested since error clearly says those are rendered as `http://`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really!

I Edited my app.blade.php file to my original Post. Not sure if the files are loaded correctly, cause I am not fluent in php or javascript.

Comment: Go with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('assets/app.css') }}">` Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-secure-asset).

Comment: Ok ill try that. Can i change this at runtime or would i have to restart apache2?

Comment: At runtime is ok. But open it in private browsing window to avoid cache falsy result check.

Comment: Ok i changed it. But i have the same result. Also tried it from a private tab and a different device so cache shouldnt be an issue. Any other idea?
Maybe I also have to change the url() to secure_assets() in these lines:
`<script src="{{ url('assets/vendor.js') }}"></script>`
`<script src="{{ url('assets/app.js') }}"></script>`

Do you have any other idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Yes, you should. For changed URL, has that one missed in error log?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, what is missing in error log?

Comment: Don't use url() helper. Use just `secure_asset('path/to/file')` helper. Is error log exact the same or using `secure_asset` you are losing some error lines there?

Comment: after replacing those 3 url() with secure_asset() i have exactly the same amount of errors in the console. By the way, thank you so much for assisting me!

Comment: It shouldn't be that way. Double check if you are looking correct blade file.

Comment: The file i'm looking at is located at client/resources/app.blade.php

Comment: Double check if that is the file meant to be loaded over controller action you are using in that route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211196/discussion-between-calgara12-and-tpojka).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to register method of AppServiceProvider.

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47341952